# Dynamically inserting directives/components into angular table cells

Tags: angularjs

I have a table directive that basically loops through an array and inserts html like this:

```
<tr ng-if="isComplete()" ng-repeat="row in paged.page()" ng-click="rowClick(row, $event)">
    <td ng-repeat="header in headers" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(header.formatter(row[header.property]))"></td>
</tr>
```

The directive is configured like this:

```
  $scope.headers = [
    comsTable.header('id', 'ID', function(id, obj) {
      return '<a href="#" ng-click="doSomething(obj)">' + id + '</a>';
    }),
    comsTable.header('name', 'Name'),
    comsTable.header('age', 'Age')
  ];
```

WHere the first argument is an object property of each element in the array.

And `ng-bind-html` is used and I can pass in html and I use `trustAsHtml` from the `$ce` service.

I am able to insert basic html like this when configuring the table:

```
  $scope.headers = [
    comsTable.header('id', 'ID', function(id, obj) {
      return '<a href="#" ng-click="doSomething(obj)">' + id + '</a>';
    }),
```

If I wanted to insert a dynamically created directive.  Can I achieve this without re-architecting the whole table.  I believe I would have to use `$compile` and attach the node/element to the DOM but could I wait until after the table has been rendered to call `$compile` or what would be the best way of achieving this?

I'm new to angular so I'm not sure of what is the best way of achieving this.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0X63VoHEQPiB6pM4yU0F?p=preview) that shows the directive I have so far